# Column start with number in Pyspark not providing Correct output

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, mapping

I have dataframe in which some column start with number and when I create new column with dict of all column and row value using below code. I am not geeting correct output.

| Name | Date | 1Y | 2Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | 2022-05-22 | 0.0898 | 0.9090 |

After running this code

```
df = df.withColumn("map", F.expr("map(" + ",".join([f"'{c}', {c}" for c in df.columns]) + ")"))
```

I am getting

| Name | Date | 1Y | 2Y | map |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | 2022-05-22 | 0.0898 | 0.9090 | {"Name":"XYZ","Date":2022-05-22","1Y":"1","2Y":"2"} |

but when I rename the columns which start with number like 1Y to Y1 and 2Y to Y2 I am geeting the correct output like below

| Name | Date | Y1 | Y2 | map |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | 2022-05-22 | 0.0898 | 0.9090 | {"Name":"XYZ","Date":2022-05-22","Y1":"0.0898","Y2":"0.9090"} |

is there any way to do this without renaming the column? I have many columns starting with numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use backticks, in SQL, while providing columns starting with numbers or special characters.

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn("map", func.expr("map(" + ", ".join([f"'{c}', `{c}`" for c in data_sdf.columns]) + ")")). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +----+----------+------+-----+------------------------------------------------------------+
# |name|date      |1Y    |2Y   |map                                                         |
# +----+----------+------+-----+------------------------------------------------------------+
# |XYZ |2022-05-22|0.0898|0.909|{name -> XYZ, date -> 2022-05-22, 1Y -> 0.0898, 2Y -> 0.909}|
# +----+----------+------+-----+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Without the backticks, the map expression would look like following

```
map('name', name, 'date', date, '1Y', 1Y, '2Y', 2Y)
```

Within an `expr()` this is executed as SQL, and thus the `1Y` is considered as the number `1`.

Using backticks, the map expression looks like following

```
map('name', `name`, 'date', `date`, '1Y', `1Y`, '2Y', `2Y`)
```

---

Alternatively, you could also use the `create_map` function.

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('map', 
               func.create_map(*reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, 
                                       [[func.lit(c), func.col(c)] for c in data_sdf.columns]
                                       )
                               )
               ). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +----+----------+------+-----+------------------------------------------------------------+
# |name|date      |1Y    |2Y   |map                                                         |
# +----+----------+------+-----+------------------------------------------------------------+
# |XYZ |2022-05-22|0.0898|0.909|{name -> XYZ, date -> 2022-05-22, 1Y -> 0.0898, 2Y -> 0.909}|
# +----+----------+------+-----+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But I Just change the variable from 1Y & 2Y to 1M & 2M. in that case code(without tick) works fine. Is there a reason? Just wanted to understand.